Flutterflow - trying to show and dismiss dialog shows 2 dialogs which I need to click OK to in order to close instead of 1
I am using the following code to open and close dialogs depending on whether there is internet connectivity or not:
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/backend/schema/structs/index.dart';
import '/backend/schema/enums/enums.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/actions/index.dart'; // Imports other custom actions
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom action code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'dart:io'; // Import Platform for checking the operating system
import 'package:internet_connection_checker_plus/internet_connection_checker_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; // Needed for closing the app
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';

class InternetConnectionMonitor {
  Timer? _timer;
  OverlayEntry? _noInternetOverlayEntry;
  OverlayEntry? _restoredInternetOverlayEntry;
  OverlayEntry? _modalBarrierEntry;
  bool _hasInternet = true;
  bool _modalBarrierShowing = false;
  BuildContext? _originalContext;
  String? _routeName;
  Completer<String>? _completer;

  Future<void> startMonitoring(BuildContext context, String language,
      String routeName, Completer<String> completer) async {
    debugPrint('Start monitoring internet connection');
    _originalContext = context;
    _routeName = routeName;
    _completer = completer;
    if (_timer == null) {
      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) async {
        await checkInternetStatus(context, language);
      });
      await checkInternetStatus(context, language); // Initial check
    }
  }

  void stopMonitoring() {
    debugPrint('Stop monitoring internet connection');
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer?.cancel();
      _timer = null;
    }
    removeDialogs();
    removeModalBarrier();
  }

  Future<void> checkInternetStatus(
      BuildContext context, String language) async {
    debugPrint('Checking internet status');
    final InternetConnection internetConnection = InternetConnection();
    final status = await internetConnection.hasInternetAccess;
    debugPrint('Internet status: ${status ? "connected" : "disconnected"}');
    if (!status && _hasInternet) {
      _hasInternet = false;
      showNoInternetDialog(context, language);
    } else if (status && !_hasInternet) {
      _hasInternet = true;
      showRestoredInternetDialog(context, language);
    }
    // Complete the completer with 'false' if there is internet connection
    if (status && _completer != null && !_completer!.isCompleted) {
      _completer!.complete('false');
    }
  }

  void showNoInternetDialog(BuildContext context, String language) {
    debugPrint('Showing no internet dialog');
    removeDialogs(); // Ensure all dialogs are removed before showing a new one
    String title = language == 'el' ? 'Χωρίς σύνδεση' : 'No Internet';
    String message = language == 'el'
        ? 'Δεν υπάρχει σύνδεση στο διαδίκτυο.'
        : 'You have no internet connection.';
    addModalBarrier(context);
    _noInternetOverlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.wifi_off, color: Colors.red),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text(title),
            ],
          ),
          content: Text(message),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint('No internet dialog OK pressed');
                removeDialogs(); // Ensure this dialog is removed properly
                removeModalBarrier();
                if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
                  exit(0);
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    if (_noInternetOverlayEntry != null && Overlay.maybeOf(context) != null) {
      Overlay.of(context).insert(_noInternetOverlayEntry!);
    }
  }

  void showRestoredInternetDialog(BuildContext context, String language) {
    debugPrint('Showing restored internet dialog');
    removeDialogs(); // Ensure all dialogs are removed before showing a new one
    String title = 'Connection Restored';
    String message = 'Your internet connection has been restored.';
    addModalBarrier(context);
    _restoredInternetOverlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.wifi, color: Colors.green),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text(title),
            ],
          ),
          content: Text(message),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint('Restored internet dialog OK pressed');
                removeDialogs(); // Ensure this dialog is removed properly
                removeModalBarrier();
                // Complete the completer with 'true' when the button is pressed
                if (_completer != null && !_completer!.isCompleted) {
                  _completer!.complete('true');
                }
                // Navigate back to the original route
                if (_originalContext != null && _routeName != null) {
                  Navigator.of(_originalContext!).pushNamed(_routeName!);
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    if (_restoredInternetOverlayEntry != null &&
        Overlay.maybeOf(context) != null) {
      Overlay.of(context).insert(_restoredInternetOverlayEntry!);
    }
  }

  void removeDialogs() {
    debugPrint('Removing all dialogs');
    if (_noInternetOverlayEntry != null) {
      _noInternetOverlayEntry!.remove();
      _noInternetOverlayEntry = null;
    }
    if (_restoredInternetOverlayEntry != null) {
      _restoredInternetOverlayEntry!.remove();
      _restoredInternetOverlayEntry = null;
    }
  }

  void addModalBarrier(BuildContext context) {
    if (_modalBarrierShowing) {
      removeModalBarrier();
    }
    debugPrint('Adding modal barrier');
    _modalBarrierShowing = true;
    _modalBarrierEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
              ),
            ),
            ModalBarrier(
              dismissible: false,
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    if (_modalBarrierEntry != null && Overlay.maybeOf(context) != null) {
      Overlay.of(context)!.insert(_modalBarrierEntry!);
    }
  }

  void removeModalBarrier() {
    if (_modalBarrierEntry != null) {
      debugPrint('Removing modal barrier');
      if (_modalBarrierEntry!.mounted) {
        _modalBarrierEntry!.remove();
      }
      _modalBarrierEntry = null;
      _modalBarrierShowing = false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> monitorInternetConnection(BuildContext context, String language,
      String routeName, Completer<String> completer) async {
    await startMonitoring(context, language, routeName, completer);
  }
}

Future<String> monitorInternetConnection(
    BuildContext context, String language, String routeName) async {
  Completer<String> completer = Completer<String>();
  InternetConnectionMonitor _monitor = InternetConnectionMonitor();
  await _monitor.startMonitoring(context, language, routeName, completer);
  return completer.future;
}

the problem I am having is that when the alert dialog 'You have internet' appears, I need to click on OK twice in order to close, which seems to be the case that 2 such dialogs open. Also, when the 'You have no internet' dialog appears, initially there is a blurred background which becomes even more blurred a little bit later, does this mean also 2 such dialogs are opened? How can I make sure 1 of each dialogs are opened, and that the 'OK' pressed once closes the dialog when there is internet?
